# React: Module parse failed: Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, webpack

started learning react 
trying to follow few instruction on internet and
 to get basic setup done but getting error below:

```
>  ERROR in ./src/index.js 7:11
>     Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:11)
```

> ```
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> |     render(){
> |        return (
> >            <div>
> |                <h1>Hello!</h1>
> |            </div>
> ```

Comment: Can you show your webpack config and babel config?

Comment: unfortunately stack overflow does not allow to add more code, it says "your questions too much of code"

Comment: So add more own comments, there are questions with a lot of code. You can alternatively use codesandbox or similar.

Comment: My guess you haven't set js/jsx file extension to be loaded with babel loader `{test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/}`

Comment: Exactly - you don't load them using loader.

Comment: `var path = require("path");

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,"dist");
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,"src");

var config = {
    entry: SRC_DIR + "/index.js",
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR + "/app",
        filename: "index.js",
        publicPath:"/app/" 
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
      },
   
};
module.exports = config;`

Comment: module: {
      loaders: [
          {
              test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
              include: SRC_DIR,
              loader: 'babel',
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              query: {
                cacheDirectory: true,
                  presets:["env","es2015","react","stage-2"]
              }
          }
      ]
     }

Comment: do you need babelrc. as well?

Answer (score 0):

Configuring webpack and babel is NOT one of the simpler steps when "started learning react", so I would recommend to use `create-react-app`.

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Your webpack config should load files using loaders. Example webpack config using webpack 4 and babel 7:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const urlLoader = require('url-loader');

// copy manifest.json to the path: 'public/build'
// this will allow for the authRequest to see the file at www.example.com/manifest.json
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    target: 'web',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js',
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        watchOptions: {aggregateTimeout: 300, poll: 1000},
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization",
        },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/},
            {test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/},
            {
                test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpe?g|gif)(\?\S*)?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
            },
            {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

**Note it's babel-loader not babel linke in your config.**
Now my dependencies:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "deep-freeze": "^0.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.28.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
```

of course some of them may be not needed in your case. Also consider using webpack-encore - it's easier version of webpack first made to easier cooperate with symfony backend but it's totally fine for other backends. See eg. webpack (-encore) config:

```
// webpack.config.js
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public')
    .setPublicPath('/')

    // read main.js     -> output as web/build/app.js
    .addEntry('js/main', './public/src/main.js')
    // read global.scss -> output as web/build/global.css
    .addStyleEntry('css/styles', './public/scss/global.scss')
    .disableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    // enable features!
    .enableSassLoader()
    .autoProvidejQuery()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction());

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```